# Declare a global module in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I declare a module which is available in all class and controllers in a rails application, I want to declare constants in this module

Also can I declare a module inside a module?

Comment: Firstly, every module in rails is global. Secondly, yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

modules will be available everywhere, but placing them in /helpers/ is a good idea.

do something like:

```
module FooBarer
  def foo_the_bars(bars)
    bar.foo_this_bar
  end
end
```

You can set global variables this way by doing something like

```
module GlobalINitializer
  def globals
   FOO = "bar"
  end
end
```

BUT

You should set globals in a config file or initializer.

If you're on Rails 4.1 you can put them in secrets.yml or put them in config/initializers in global_foos.rb ehich would look like

```
#global foos
FOO = "bar"
THIS_THING = "that thing"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, can:

```
module A
  module ::MyGLobalModule
    def hello
      puts "hello"
    end
  end
end

class B
  extend ::MyGlobalModule
end

B.hello
```